DynamoDB consistency
I'm building an web application, which uses DynamoDB as its database. I understand by default DynamoDB is eventual consistency. My application is set up such that the user is only interested in their data, that means a user won't depend on other dynamic data, but their own.
Let's say a user reads(GET) their name=hello. They change(POST) it to name=world.
Can the subsequent GET be guaranteed to be name=world? I'm talking about the case where the user sits in front of one machine at a one geographical location.
Another question is that if I configure DynamoDB to 'consistent read', would that solve the problem if the answer to above is no?
Thank you for any feedback in advance!

Does this answer your question? AWS DynamoDB read after write consistency - how does it work theoretically?

The first answer is no, it's not guaranteed but is usually up to date within a millisecond but because you cannot guarantee that, then you must configure your reads to be consistent.
Consistency can be set on a per request basis, and 90% of use cases can tolerate the couple of milliseconds lag in consistency.
Have a read of the docs for more info.

Thank you for the answer, the docs has my next question about the pricing difference between eventual and consistent.
